# Rails: How to use includes with conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a ressource Room that has_many reservations. Likewise the ressource Reservation belongs_to a room.

My reservation model has a starts_at and an ends_at attribute.

In my index action for the Room controller I want to get all the Rooms and include all the reservations for a certain date(the date is given as a parameter).

I have tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

```
@rooms = Room.includes(:reservations).where("reservations.starts_at" => params[:date])
```

I am aware that this code does not take into account that a room could be reserved for multiple days, but I had to start somewhere.

**SUM UP**

Based on a date the action should return all the rooms, but only include the reservations that is relevant for that date.

**EDIT**

This is what I ended up doing.

***controllers/rooms_controller.rb***

```
def index
  @rooms = Room.includes(:reservations)
  @date = params[:date] ||= Date.today
end
```

***views/rooms/index.html.haml***

```
- @rooms.each do |room|
  - room.reservations.relevant(@date).each do |reservation|
    = reservation.id
```

***models/reservation.rb***

```
def self.relevant(date = Date.today)
  if date.blank?
    date = Date.today
  end
  where(
    '(starts_at BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (ends_at BETWEEN ? AND ?)',
    date.to_date.beginning_of_day, date.to_date.end_of_day, 
    date.to_date.beginning_of_day, date.to_date.end_of_day
  )
end
```

It works alright, but the view is talking to the model I think?

Answer (score 1):

If your `where` conditions refer to another table then you also need to need to specify `references` as well as `includes`. e.g.

```
@rooms = Room.includes(:reservations).
    where("reservations.starts_at" => params[:date]).
    references(:reservations)
```

See the API documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references).

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it doesn't seem to work for me. I don't get any error messages, it just seems like the @rooms variable is empty.

Comment: You didn't specify in your question, but I assume before adding `references` you were getting an error? I'd suggest trying out the query in the Rails console before incorporating it in your controller. Check the data in your `reservations` table to be sure there is at least one reservation with the start date you've specified.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to specify that. The code I had before had the same effect. It basically sent the @rooms controller to the view with nothing in it. I did make sure there was a reservation with my params[:date] in the table. But just now I am realizing, the reservation.starts_at and .ends_at are datetimes, could that be what is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think that could be the part of the problem. Try doing a match on a simpler field to start with. e.g. just the `id` of a reservation. Can you successfully run a query that finds the `Room` that goes with a specific reservation id.

Comment: Yes, but it only returns the room that has that reservation with a specific id.

Comment: Ok, so that tells you that the basic structure of your query is correct now and the issue is just on doing a match on the date field. Do you want to change the `starts_at` field to a `starts_on` date field? Get the date query working just using `Reservation.where...` before combing it with `Room`

Comment: I rather not change the field for various reasons. But I have made another where statement that seems to work for now. But there is still the problem that I only get the printers with relevant reservations. I need all printers, but only the relevant reservations.

Comment: If you use `Room.where`... this is going to restrict which rooms get loaded. The idea of the `includes` is to prevent an individual query being run to retrieve the reservations for each room when you refer to the reservations on a room later. If you want all rooms (or printers?) then you need to load those and then filter the reservations after.

Comment: Sorry for the room/printers confusion. Ok, so how should I go about getting all the rooms and then printing out the relevant reservations for a given date. I have the `.where()` query working fine.

Comment: Sorry for delay in following up. Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: I did, but it is not very pretty. And I think I have the view talking to the model, so it is not an ideal solution. I will make an edit of what I have done, and maybe you can tell me a way to improve it?

Comment: I'd say making a call to a method on the model from the view in this way is fine (it's adding too much complex logic to the view that should be avoided). The only thing I'd say about this code is that it's going to run a separate query to look up the matching reservations for a single room each time you call `relevant`. This means that your `includes(:reservations)` which is loading the full list of reservations is running a query whose results are then not being used.

Comment: So I should remove `includes(:reservations)`?

Comment: The number of rooms and reservations you're showing at once would determine whether you need to optimise this. For example, if you show 10 rooms at a time this would currently be 11 or 12 queries (one query to load the rooms, one query to load the reservations through `includes` and then 10 queries, one for each room when you use `relevant`. If you keep the `includes` then you could move the logic for `relevant` to a method on `Room` e.g. `revervations_on(date)` which would use Ruby code to filter the list of already-loaded reservations without running any additional queries.